# Table Layout and CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my .css as my `<table>` is not centered and stays left.
I tried the `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto` without success.
Am I missing a `<div>` tag for my table, I have set an `id="content"` to try to center it but does not work.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Assignment 5: Retouching Images</title>
<meta name="description" content="retouching images, photoshop">
<meta name="keywords" content="images, modify, photoshop">
<link href="css/rtouch.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"> <img src="images/logoheader.jpg" alt="Armchair Bookstore Logo" width="975" height="230" class="floatcenter"> </div>
    <!-- header  section ends --> 

    <!-- menu  section starts -->
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" id="current" class="first">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="newrelease.html">New Releases</a></li>
            <li><a href="placeholder.html">Special Selection</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="placeholder.html">On Sale</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- menu  section ends -->
    <div id="content">
        <table class="center">
            <caption>
            Image Modification
            </caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Original Image</th>
                    <th>Retouched Image</th>
                    <th>Specifications</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td ><img src="images/wedding_org_thumb.jpg" alt="Original Wedding Photo Thumbnail" width="100" height="80" class="floatcenter"></td>
                    <td ><img src="images/wedding_rt_thumb.jpg" alt="Retouched Wedding Photo Thumbnail" width="100" height="80" class="floatcenter"></td>
                    <td>350 x 280 at 72 DPI</td>
                    <td>Blablablablabla</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td ><img src="images/redeye_org_thumb.jpg" alt="Original Redeye Baby Photo Thumbnail" width="100" height="131" class="floatcenter"></td>
                    <td ><img src="images/redeye_rt_thumb.jpg" alt="Retouched Redeye Baby Photo Thumbnail" width="100" height="115" class="floatcenter"></td>
                    <td>350 x 280 at 72 DPI</td>
                    <td>Blablablablabla</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td ><img src="images/balloons_org_thumb.jpg" alt="Original Balloon Photo Thumbnail" width="100" height="66" class="floatcenter"></td>
                    <td ><img src="images/balloons_rt_thumb.jpg" alt="Retouched Balloon Photo Thumbnail" width="100" height="83" class="floatcenter"></td>
                    <td>350 x 280 at 72 DPI</td>
                    <td>Blablablablabla</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> <br>
    Copyright &copy; 2012 JC Design. All Rights Reserved | 1.800.604.6305 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .CSS

```
/*Body*/
html {background-color: #e2e2e2}

body 
{ 
   color: #000; background: #fff;
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue",helvetica,arial, sans; 
   font-size: 90%;
   text-align: left;
   width: 975px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

fieldset
{
   margin: 25px;
   border-radius: 15px;
}

p {
   margin-left: 25px;
   margin-right: 30px;
   text-align: left;
}

/*General link formatting*/

a:link 
{ 
   color: #f60; background: #fff; 
} 
a:visited 
{ 
   color: #f60;
} 
a:hover 
{ 
   color: #00aed7;  
   text-decoration: none; 
} 
a:active 
{ 
   color: #000; 
}

/*Page wrapper*/
#wrapper 
{ 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   width: 975px; 
   text-align: left;
}

/*Banner styles*/
#header {

   width: 975px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-top: 0px;
}

#footer
{  background-color: #04346c; color: #fff;
   font-family: "Helvectica Neue,",helvetica, arial, sans;
   font-size: 80%;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-align: center;
   width: 955px;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-top: 5px;
}
 /*---------------Navigation  styles-------------------*/

#menu {
  float: left; 
  margin:0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #04346c; color: #fff;
}  


#menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative 
}


#menu ul li {
  display: inline; 
}


#menu ul li a {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background: #437DD4; color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}


#menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff; background: #0f4da8;
  text-decoration: underline;

}

#menu li a#current {
  background: #6a94d4; color: #fff;
}

/*Navbar styles*/
#navcontainer 
{ 
   width: 975px; 
   background: #04346c; color: #fff; 
   padding: 5px 0;
   font-weight: bold;
} 
#navcontainer p 
{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 6px; 
   text-align: center; 
} 
#navcontainer p a 
{ 
   padding: 4px 10px; 
   color: #fff; background: #04346c;
   font-size: 120%;
}     
#navcontainer p a:hover 
{ 
   background: #4284d3; 
   text-decoration: none; 
}

#navcontainer p a#current 
{ 
   text-decoration: none; 
   padding: 4px 10px; 
   border: none; 
}   
/*Content styles*/


.floatright 
{ 
   float: right; 
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 1px; 
   border: none;  
}
.floatright2 
{ 
   float: right; 
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 1px; 
   border: none;
}


/*Headings*/

legend
{
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 120%;
   color: #224080;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
h1
{
   margin-left: 20px;
   padding: 2px;

}

h2
{
   margin-left: 25px;
   font-size: 110%;
}
/*Table styles*/

#table 
{ 
margin-left: 45px;
margin-right: 45px;

   border-collapse: collapse;


}
#table.center 
{ 
   position: relative;
   margin: auto; 
   border-collapse: collapse;


}

td, th 
{ 
   border-style: none; 
   border-width: thin; 
   border-color: #000; 
   padding: 15px; 
   border-collapse: collapse;

}
caption
{
   width: auto;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   padding: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #f60;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
#content {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you filter out only what is necessary so we don't have to dig through 10 million lines of code?

Comment: Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9RCZY/

As someone already suggested, your CSS selector is wrong.  #table and #table.center will not match your table.  The # selector is to match a certain element by ID.  Your table has no ID, but it has a class, so your CSS selector should be .center (or table.center for more specificity).

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have this

```
#table.center 
{ 
  position: relative;
  margin: auto; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

you need to change it to this

```
.center 
{ 
   position: relative;
   margin: auto; 
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

This is because # refers to an ID. In your HTML code you do not have and id table.

Following on from Piotr Lewandowski suggestion, it is better to remove unnecessary ids from html code and css

Comment: Thank you..and yes, sorry for the unused codes..Will clean up in future.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to your table element:

```
<table class="center" id="table">
```

`#table` selector couldn't select  element